# stuff literal dollar sign into existing screen

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I have a screen running in the background. I want to programmatically send a command to that screen. I have been doing that like this:

`screen -x <screen.PID> -p 0 -X stuff 'echo $varname'`

and it has been working fine. However I recently upgraded my version of `screen` from `4.00.03` to `4.03.01` and the same command no longer works. Now, `screen` intercepts my command and eval's the shell variable before it is printed. So for instance instead of sending

`echo $varname`

it will send

`echo var_value`

if `$varname="var_value"`. One solution is to escape `$` in my command--which works for the newer version of screen, but then it does not work on the older version. I would like to find a command that works on all versions, as my script is deployed on many machines and I can't be sure which version of `screen` is installed (or when exactly this change was made in `screen`).

Comment: FWIW it works OK with `screen` *v4.6.1* on *Lubuntu v17.10*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to construct a conditional that branched depending on whether the screen version requires escaping. Suppose you have a screen in which `varname=1` and you want to `echo $varname`. If you `stuff` the following code into the screen it will work on both versions of screen:

```
if [ -z $varname ];
then echo \$varname;
else echo $varname;
fi;
```

Why it works:

On the older version of screen that does not require $ to be escaped, the conditional `[ -z $varname ]` will eval to false since `$varname` exists and is not empty. In newer versions of screen, `$varname` will be parsed before the conditional and the statement that actually executes is `[ -z ]`. This evals to true, and so the first branch is executed.

Comment: This approach will fail to work if the variable `varname` is defined in the `screen`'s environment

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It *only* works when `varname` is defined in the screen's environment.

Comment: I mean the environment of the `screen` process itself rather than the environment inside the screen sessions. For example, try to use the `HOME` variable with your approach.

Comment: In that case, it will substitute `$HOME` for your home directory in the new screen. I just tried in both screen versions and it works fine, though there may be an edge case I'm unaware of that doesn't work.

Comment: What about a variable that exits and has different values in the environment of the `screen` process and inside the screen session, (e.g. `$PWD`, provided that you've changed to another directory inside the screen session)?

Comment: It evals the screen's $PWD, which is expected

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to split the string that you want to send to the screen session at the `$` sign:

```
screen -x <screen.PID> -p 0 -X stuff 'echo $'
screen -x <screen.PID> -p 0 -X stuff 'varname'
```

I have checked that this works with screen version `4.03.01` and I don't see why it shouldn't work with other versions that don't try to expand variables in the `stuff` command.

**EDIT**

The string splitting can be automated as follows:

```
echo -n 'PUT YOUR STRING HERE' | {while read -r -d '$' x; do screen -x <screen.PID> -p 0 -X stuff "$x\$"; done; screen -x <screen.PID> -p 0 -X stuff "$x"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending literal text via screen stuff has many gotchas, such as the dollar sign, the circumflex, backslash, quoting, and a quite small buffer size on the screen side. None of this is documented, and similarly to the original question I needed to be able to send arbitrary text this way for a project. So a while back I wrote a Python module to take care of all the cases, it's available via pip in the lagoon project, and here is a github link: https://github.com/combatopera/lagoon/blob/master/screen.py